# ASP.NET VNC Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask about options I have in creating VNC Viewer (Client?) in ASP.NET. So far, I've found noVNC, but I'm not sure about implementing it in ASP.NET. I've have only been playing with it for a while, but maybe you could guys give me some more hints about noVNC or other options I have?

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever implement this? I've been tasked with researching its feasibilty

Comment: It's my final project on my University. Still working on it. So far, it's doable. Have not found anything else than noVNC though. You can message me if you have any specific questions and I'll try to answer them as best as I can.